# Facebook login - what on earth am I doing wrong

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm tearing my hair out here.

We've got a web app that is hosted on a bunch of different domains and we have a facebook login on the page. This works just peachy. Most of them run of our root domain eg newsite.ourplatform.com and we reuse the same facebook app and add a new domain in.

We've had a request to set up a new site on a different url. In the past, this hasn't really been a problem. We set up a new facebook app, add the appid to out config and voila, facebook login working. (we don't do this so often, so I've potentially broken it)

This time around. I've set up a new app id and plugged it in, but whenever I call the facebook login, it authenticates me, but I get a useless response from facebook.

eg. On a working site I call

```
FB.api("/me/", function(response){console.log(JSON.stringify(response));});
```

and get response

```
   "{id":"12345678910","email":"my@email.com","first_name":"My Name","gender":"male","last_name":"Myname","link":"https://www.facebook.com/app_scoped_user_id/12345678910/","locale":"en_GB","name":"My Name","timezone":10,"updated_time":"2014-01-19T10:44:20+0000","verified":true}
```

but on the broken site I do the same call and get a response

```
{"name":"MyName","id":"12345678910"}
```

Which is sort of good, but I need their email. As far as I can tell, I'm not asking for any permissions beyond email,public_profile and user_friends
Because of the way the app setup works, we have different apps running 2.1, 2.2 and 2.4 and this new one on 2.4 doesn't work. I'm not sure if that's a red herring or if I've got a misconfigured facebook app.

(edit - removed the sites affected to protect the innocent)

Comment: You need to go read the API v2.4 changelog. https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/changelog#v2_4_changes

Comment: Did you find any fix for this?

Comment: unfortunately not. going to have to start from scratch to work out what the issue is.

Comment: CBroe etc was correct, it's in the changelog. I didn't spot it initially though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @CBroe said you really need to checkout the [v2.4 changelog](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/changelog#v2_4_changes) for the API. In version 2.4 of the API Facebook introduced 'declarative fields'. This means that when you make a base request, like to `/me` you will only get a small amount of info back, e.g. 'name' and 'id'.

You have two options to get more fields:

**Option One**

```
FB.api('/me?fields=first_name,last_name,gender', function(response) {
  console.log(response)
});
```

**Option Two**

```
FB.api('/me', function(response) {
  console.log(response)
}, {'fields': 'first_name, last_name, gender'})
```

This will return a response that looks like the following:

```
{"first_name":"First", "last_name":"Last", "gender":"gender", "id":"ID"}
```

The key in the request above is specifying the `fields` URL parameter in your request and is documented in the link @CBroe linked and I have linked above.

Comment: I looked through the changelog but I couldn't see anything in the haystack of changes. I mistakenly though CBroe was giving me a RTFM answer. My apologies.